# SCSS compilation issue in @material/button/_mixins.scss

Tags: reactjs, material-design

[issue-screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjT8n.png)
I'm getting this issue it's quite troublesome can anyone please help me out reagarding this issue...
I'm getting this issue when trying to build my react project.

[build script screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r569M.png)

[node-sass already addedd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce9dY.png)

Comment: Please provide your code

Answer (score 0):

To get MDC React Components to work with create-react-app you need to set a SASS_PATH environment variable that points to your node_modules directory. To quickly do this on OS X or Linux enter the following in your command line:

```
export SASS_PATH=./node_modules
```

If you're on Windows use the following:

`SET SASS_PATH=.\node_modules`

Rename your src/App.css file to src/App.scss.

You will also need to install node-sass:

```
npm install node-sass
```

Comment: Amit sorry for the trouble caused you.. I checked package.json then found that the 
changes you suggested were already made by a team mate but then also it's failing...

Comment: Then you can do rm -rf node_modules and then do yarn && yarn start